# stretch grid child element storyboard scale wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, storyboard

Stretching child grid element after storyboard animation. How to stop stretching a Grid child elements 
here is storyboard code

```xml
  <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard_FullScreenSensor">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridM">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1.088"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1.417"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridM">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-3"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="-15"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

and GridM code which contain many view items e.g. Buttons, Images

```xml
 <Grid 
        x:Name="GridM" 
        Height="340" Margin="0,85,0,0"
  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>

        <Grid 
        Name="GridLoader"
        >
// code
        </Grid>

        <ContentControl 
            x:Name="" 
            >
            //code

        </ContentControl>

        <Grid
            Name="GridChild"
/>
</Grid>
```

After animation of storyboard stretch all childs in Media grid
show as 
[image]

Required view is 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In storyboard if use `Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)"` which stretching that grid. Solve by using

```
 <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridM">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="480"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="800"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

or

```
 <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridM">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="340"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="480"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

it animate width or hight of perticular component when start storyboard.Begin()